# Simple Data Edit Screen from Parameter C# SQL Server Visual Studio 15

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a grid on Form1 from which the user selects a row.  The key value from that row is sent via parameter to Form2.  All I want to do is to display the data from that row, allow edits, update the database and return to Form1.  Such a simple task and I feel like it's insurmountable.

I have my database connected and I'm trying to get the .FillBy thing working.

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iSOTableAdapter.FillBy(MYDataSet.CustomerDataTable "Customer","123456");

    }
```

The "123456" is the parameter for the query.  I get the error on that line that ; is expected and MYDataSet.CustomerDataTable is a type which is not valid in the current context.   Earlier in the code, I have

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2(string grdValue)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(grdValue);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

but I can't get grdValue to work in the .FillBy either.   Please help!!!

Comment: Okay - I got the fill to work by making a new query FillByGrdValue and filling it using this call:  this.iSOTableAdapter.FillByGrdValue(MYDataSet.CustomerDataTable.Customer, grdValue);    It works when I put a literal in but it doesn't work when I put grdValue.  For some reason, it can't see the grdValue that I declared earlier when I received it as a parameter.  I'd appreciate any help on how to make that visible.

Comment: This is how I ended up doing it.  Declare   public int grdValue2; outside of  public Form2(int grdValue) then assigned grdValue to it within Form2
 grdValue2 = grdValue;    Of course all you have to do is post a question for a solution to appear.